# Installing `tezos-client` on Apple Mac OS M1

Tags: tezos-client

I tried to install `tezos-client` by using M1 version of homebrew (`brew install tezos-client`). and I received this error.

```
/opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github/api.rb:304:in `raise_error': Validation Failed: [{"message"=>"The listed users and repositories cannot be searched either because the resources do not exist or you do not have permission to view them.", "resource"=>"Search", "field"=>"q", "code"=>"invalid"}] (GitHub::API::ValidationFailedError)
```

I tried installing with x86-64 architecture with Rosetta homebrew but I received this error instead:

```
/usr/local/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/utils/github.rb:60:in `issues_for_formula': undefined method `full_name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is it possible to install tezos on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [this Tezos MR](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/merge_requests/2462) will allow Tezos to be built on MacOS arm64.

However, while it has been merged, its changes are not yet included in the current latest release ([v10.0.0](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/releases/10.0.0)) AFAICT.

A `tezos-packaging` user was reportedly able to use [this workaround](https://github.com/serokell/tezos-packaging/issues/205#issuecomment-871438693) using rosetta, it might help you as well.